# Is this method of transitioning between color animations in React Native flawed?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let's say I have an element with an animated background color, perhaps mid-animation. I suddenly want to animate to a new background color smoothly. This is the way I've been doing it:

```
  let endColor = "#ffffff";
  let startColor = JSON.stringify(this.interpolations.backgroundColor);
  this.interpolations.backgroundColor = this.animations.backgroundColor.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [startColor, endColor]
  });
  Animated.timing(this.animations.backgroundColor, {
    toValue: 0,
    duration: 0
  }).start();
  Animated.timing(this.animations.backgroundColor, {
    toValue: 100,
    duration: 500
  }).start();
```

But this method is causing weird bugs where the transition doesn't happen or happen in flawed ways I can't seem to pinpoint, and overall it's too much code to ask about here. So I just want to know if there's a flaw in this method and if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can solve it by giving a short duration for the sudden change and chaining the next animation.

```
Animated.timing(this.animations.backgroundColor, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 1
}).start(() => {
   Animated.timing(this.animations.backgroundColor, {
     toValue: 100,
     duration: 500
   }).start();
});
```